# Zend_Auth multiple credentials?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

Login Form:

```
    $authAdapter    = Zend_Registry::get('authAdapter');
    $authAdapter
  ->setIdentity($formData['email'])
  ->setCredential($password)
  ->setCredential(1);
```

Bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initAuth(){
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $this->bootstrap('session');

    $db             = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
    $auth           = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $authAdapter    = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'User', 'email', 'password', 'enabled');

    Zend_Registry::set('authAdapter', $authAdapter);
    return $authAdapter;
}
```

Obviously since adding 'enabled' its stopped working, if I remove:

```
->setCredential(1);
```

and 'enabled' from there:

```
($db, 'User', 'email', 'password', 'enabled');
```

it works just fine...

I would like to only enable users who have an enabled account to login though.

EDIT:

```
        $authAdapter    = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'User', 'email', 'password', '(?) AND `enabled` = 1');
```

works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your adapter like so:

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
    $db,
    'user',
    'email',
    'password',
    'MD5(?) AND `enabled` = "true"');
```

Answer (score 1):

please try:

```
$authAdapter    = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'User', 'email', 'password', 'AND enabled      > 1');
```

and remove:

```
->setCredential(1);
```

Comment: This didn't work. Infact I changed 'AND `enabled` = "1"' to 'AND jimmy = blah' and it still logged in, leading me to believe its ignored that last field!

Comment: See first post: it was:

  $authAdapter    = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'User', 'email', 'password', '(?) AND `enabled` = 1');

Comment: how about this:
$authAdapter    = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'User', 'email', 'password');

and then 

$select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where('enabled = 1');

$authAdapter->authenticate();

which ZF version are you using? thx

Comment: isn't this solution to this problem a bit hacky?

Answer (score 0):

You can set additional conditions in the auth adapter i.e.

```
$select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where("isActive = ?","Active");
```